# Can’t set up 4K resolution on new PC after cloning Linux Kubuntu SSD from laptop with Clonezilla

Tags: ubuntu, display, kubuntu, resolution, clonezilla

SOLVED! THE REAL PROBLEM WAS MY HARDWARE:
I tried running Kubuntu in a live environment through my USB and I had the same problem (and in the windows setup then as well, but I didn't notice). After that I started looking for possible hardware problems and found my PC on this list:  https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000126548/resolution-on-external-monitor-limited-to-1920-x-1080-using-hdmi
My PC's motherboard doesn't support 4K over HDMI (only DP), so I'll have to get a display port cable.

TLDR AT THE END
I recently cloned my SSD with Clonezilla from a laptop with Linux Kubuntu to a new desktop PC. Both SSDs were 500gb, the laptop has a 12th gen i5 processor, and the PC has a 13th gen i7 processor, and there are no separate GPUs . The laptop’s default display is its 1080p built-in display. I've connected the new PC to a new 4K monitor, but it can only display 1080p on the monitor. I suspect it’s an issue with cloning from the laptop because I can connect the monitor to my laptop and have it display 4K without any issues (with the exact same hard drive information as the PC which can’t do this).
I don’t know what exactly is going on, but based on this I suspect that the PC thinks that the primary display it’s dealing with is still my laptop’s 1080p built-in display and that there is no (easy) way to change that. The first time I booted into Linux on my new PC, the screen was shrinked to 1080p and centered on the monitor, and when I restarted it was across the entire monitor screen but it was scaled down to 1080p and it's remained that way since. Additionally, the Dell BIOS and the Windows installation the PC came with could both display 4K on any 4K monitor.
Here's what I've tried so far:
1. Checked cable connections and the monitor. 4K works on other laptops and PCs without issues. The same problem is present with my PC if I connect it to any other 4K monitor as well.
2. Made sure the system (and the kernel) are up-to-date.
3. Tried to add the resolution with xrandr and failed (both with 30Hz and 60Hz):

```
user:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 3840x2160
xrandr: cannot find mode 3840x2160
user:~$ WLR_DRM_NO_MODIFIERS=1
user:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 3840x2160
xrandr: cannot find mode 3840x2160
user:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
user:~$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00" 297.0 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "3840x2160_30.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "3840x2160_30.00"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

4. Added the new resolution with the „cvt“ command, after which I could see it in xrandr and in system settings. However, when I selected the 4K resolution nothing would happen (the display would just remain at 1080p, confirmed by checking the built-in monitor information).

Here is also my output from xrandr –verbose (my monitor is connected with HDMI 2):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x42
        Timestamp:  382787
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:     HDMI-1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        subconnector: Unknown 
                supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CONNECTOR_ID: 236 
                supported: 236
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x43
        Timestamp:  382787
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:     DP-1
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (8, 12)
        content type: No Data 
                supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
        aspect ratio: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CONNECTOR_ID: 249 
                supported: 249
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 632mm x 360mm
        Identifier: 0x44
        Timestamp:  382787
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.1:1.1
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        _KDE_SCREEN_INDEX: 1 
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff004c2d1710454d4e30
                23210103803f24782ac8b5ad50449e25
                0f5054bfef80714f810081c081809500
                a9c0b300010108e80030f2705a80b058
                8a0078682100001e000000fd00324b1e
                873c000a202020202020000000fc004c
                5532385235350a2020202020000000ff
                00484e4d573830303835340a20200195
                020335f04961120313041f10605f2309
                070783010000e305c0006b030c001000
                b8442000200167d85dc40178800be306
                0501e20f81023a801871382d40582c45
                0078682100001e023a80d072382d4010
                2c458078682100001e04740030f2705a
                80b0588a0078682100001e565e00a0a0
                a029503020350078682100001a000049
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (8, 12)
        content type: No Data 
                supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
        aspect ratio: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CONNECTOR_ID: 255 
                supported: 255
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x46) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x47) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x48) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x49) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x900 (0x4a) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4b) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4c) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x4d) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x800 (0x4e) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x4f) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x50) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x51) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x52) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x53) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x54) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x55) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x56) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x57) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x58) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x59) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x5a) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0x5b) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x5c) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x5d) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x5e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x5f) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x60) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x61) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x62) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x63) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x7a4) 712.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock 134.18KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock  59.98Hz
```

I've also tried some other things which I can't remember right now, but none of them worked. Do you think there's a way to fix this or should I just give up?

Also, is it possible to install a fresh Linux Kubuntu installation on my PC (which I assume would solve the problem), copy the monitor configuration files or something if that's possible, clone my laptop SSD again with Clonezilla and then paste the monitor configuration files/settings from the fresh installation into my laptop clone. Is this possible? I'm not that experienced with Linux, so I have no idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TL;DR:
Cloned Linux Kubuntu installation with Clonezilla from laptop to PC. PC can't display 4K on monitor (only 1080p), but the laptop can. The laptop's built in display is 1080p. The PC could display 4K in Dell BIOS and Windows, and the monitor (as well as its cables) work on all other PCs/laptops, leading me to believe the problem is software related and has to do with cloning from the laptop to a PC (I assume the PC „thinks“ the main display is still the laptop's built-in display). Most common workarounds found online, such as adding the resolution with „xrandr“ didn't work. Using the „cvt“ command added the resolution to xrandr and system settings, but changing the resolution does nothing. Is there a way to fix this? Would creating a new Linux Kubuntu installation and copying some monitor configuration files to the cloned installation fix things?

Comment: question: when you just boot from a Kubuntu live medium (like, for example, the installer), does it work?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, it doesn't. Thanks for pointing that out, it actually helped me find the problem. It didn't work in the windows setup either but I thought it did because of the different scaling.

Anyway, when I realised that it doesn't work on the live medium, I started searching for a hardware problem and found my PC model on this list:
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000126548/resolution-on-external-monitor-limited-to-1920-x-1080-using-hdmi

My motherboard doesn't support 4K over HDMI, so I'll have to get a Display Port cable.